# Plot an example for some functions

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear, boundary-conditions

Today I just wanted to run this code but I have some difficulty if you can have a look?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = 0.7; k = -0.04; f = 0.2; b = 1;
g[x_] :=  Sqrt[ a + f^2/(4 b^2)] / a  ArcCoth[ Sqrt[a + f^2/(4 b^2)] /Sqrt[ (1 - 2/(3 b)) x^-2 k + a + ((f^2)/(4  b^2)) ]] - f/(2 a b)Log[(3 f + 6 b Sqrt[ a + f^2/(4 b^2) + (1 - 2/(3 b)) x^-2 k]) x];
  h[x_] := g[x] - g[1];
  s[x_] := D[h[x], x]
  Plot[h[x], {x, 0, 100}]
  Plot[s[x]/h[x], {x, 0, 100}]
  ParametricPlot[{h[x], x}, {x, 1, 20}, AspectRatio -> 1]
  ParametricPlot[{s[x]/h[x], x}, {x, 1, 20}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Comment: Change it to do `Plot[Evaluate@s[x], {x, 0, 100}]`

Comment: I fixed the first part but second is not working
Plot[Evaluate@(s[x]/h[x]), {x, 0, 100}]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate@(s[x]/h[x]), {x, 1, 20}, AspectRatio -> 1]

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = 7/10; k = -4/100; f = 2/10; b = 1;
g[x_] := Sqrt[a + f^2/(4 b^2)]/a ArcCoth[
     Sqrt[a + f^2/(4 b^2)]/
      Sqrt[(1 - 2/(3 b)) x^-2 k + a + ((f^2)/(4 b^2))]] - 
   f/(2 a b) Log[(3 f + 
        6 b Sqrt[a + f^2/(4 b^2) + (1 - 2/(3 b)) x^-2 k]) x];
h[x_] := g[x] - g[1];
s[x_] := D[h[x], x]
Plot[h[x], {x, 0, 100}]
Plot[Evaluate[s[x]/h[x]], {x, 0, 100}]
ParametricPlot[{h[x], x}, {x, 1, 20}, AspectRatio -> 1]
ParametricPlot[{s[x]/h[x], x}, {x, 1, 20}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Evaluated -> True]
```

It is due to using derivatives, you want to make sure the arguments passed to the function remain symbolic before being send to the plotting functions.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> In Fig.4 it is possible extended the x axis from 0<x<10 ?!!

```
ParametricPlot[{s[x]/h[x], x}, {x, 1, 20}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, Automatic}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In Fig.4 it is possible extended the x axis from 0<x<10  ?!!

Comment: @FelipeDura updated

Comment: ParametricPlot[{s[x]/h[x], x}, {x, 0, 7}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Evaluated -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 6}}]